# Remove part of URL with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need remove prefix `/en` from all URL, eg.

```
www.mydomain.com/en/foo/bar/index.html -> www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/index.html
```

I've tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^/en/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/en/\d+-(.+) /$1 [R,L]
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [NC,L]
```

Because in `.htaccess`, `RewriteRule` first URL never starts with `/`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but it seems not work, placed in `.htaccess` file

Comment: And like that (after edit) ? Do you try to change the url or just to rewrite. Where is the real file (with or without /en/) ?

Comment: OK it works in this way, `RewriteRule ^en/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L]`, thanks (modify your answer)